# If we have two functions that have composition differentiable does it mean both are differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ are functions such that $g \circ f$ differentiable does it mean both are differentiable ? I just need this for differential geometry. Suppose I know the following fact $proj : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $u : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ where $proj \circ u$ is differentiable does it mean that u is differentiable ? Here proj is the regular projection function.

Comment: Take $f$ any function and $g=0$.

Comment: when what I said holds ?

Comment: As Aloizio notes, you need to impose more conditions on $f$ and $g$ to get something interesting.

Comment: I have edited my question to exactly what I mean.

Comment: @Adeek given all those examples of counter-examples, you can easily find one for the case $g = proj$

Comment: @Adeek: It would be good to ask your edited question (I suspect you mean to ask whether, if the coordinate projections of $u$ are _all_ differentiable, is $u$ itself differentiable) _as a separate question_ rather than edit here. The difference is large enough that the existing answers don't do much to answer the amended question.

Comment: Seconding @HenningMakholm 's suggestion. I note that you have accepted an answer to your original question that does not answer the new one. Please revert this one to the way it was, leave it here since it's interesting, and ask the new one as a new question.

Comment: I will ask a new question @EthanBolker

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, neither $f$ nor $g$ needs to be differentiable.

Take e.g. $f$ to be the sign function and take $g$ to be the absolute value function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Neither is differentiable at $x=0$, but the composition is constant $=1$.

The answer to the second question is also no: Composing e.g. $u(x, y)=(0, \left|x \right|)$ with the projection onto the first component gives the constant function $=0$.

Comment: I have edited my question @damian Reding can you please check it.

Comment: What kind of sign function are you using? The one described in Wikipedia - and the one I know - has $sgn(0) = 0$.

Comment: True. Here you need $sgn(0)=1$.

Answer (score 15):

No.

Let both $f$ and $g$ be the famous function that takes rational numbers to $1$ and irrational numbers to $0$. Then, since $g$ takes all numbers to rational numbers, $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))=1$, which is certainly differentiable. But neither $f$ nor $g$ is continuous anywhere, much less differentiable.

Comment: I have edited my question @rory Daulton.

Comment: I think it should be $f(g(x)) = 1$ since $g(x)$ is rational and $f$ takes rational numbers to $1$.

Comment: @frececroka: Oops, you are right, how embarrassing. I'll edit that now. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding another fun example: $f(x)=|x|$ and $g(x)=x^2$. This is why it is often better to use $g$, a smooth funcition, as your notion of distance in contexts like linear regression.