# Condition to compostion of two maps is differentiable implies each map is differential?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, differential

Let $f:L\rightarrow M$ and $g:M\rightarrow N$ are homeomorphic, $L,M,N$ is normed vector spaces, $g\circ f$ is Fréchet differentiable. In which condition both $f,g$ are Fréchet differentiable? Can we say more when $L,M,N$ are $\mathbf{R}^n$?

Comment: Do you mean "differentiable"... Standard usage is, differential of a differentiable function... what do you mean "homeomorphic sujective"? As far as I know, all homeomorphisms are surjective...

Comment: @ Praphulla Koushik, check my edited question

Comment: with out knowing if they are manifolds, how do you talk about differentiability of maps between them? Do you know they are smooth manifolds? If so, mention it in the question..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, thank, check the edited question.

Comment: I am seeing for the first time notion of differentiability occuring in the set up of normed linear spaces.. If. you have seen this somewhere can you please copy the question correctly.

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik, thank for your patient! Here I use *Fréchet differentiable* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fréchet_derivative. From this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1949924/300871, I wonder in which condition to $g,f$ are differentiable? and put the question in more general case (normed vector space). Check my edited question

Comment: Is there some specific sort of condition you are looking for?  I wouldn't think that there is any useful condition; knowing that $g\circ f$ is differentiable just doesn't really tell you anything about whether $f$ and $g$ are.

Comment: Even with all the spaces being $\Bbb R$, if you have $f(x)=|x|$ and $g(x)=x^2$, then $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are both (infinitely) differentiable, but of course $f$ is not.